# How to change database url variable in heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, psycopg2

I'm trying to setup a simple Flask app using a postgresql database. I'm connecting to the database using psycopg2. Psycopg2 expect a dsn string for the connection, something like this :

```
dbname=mydb user=myuser password=1234 host=myhost.com
```

but heroku gives me, in my app config, a database url like this :

```
postgres://myuser:mypassword@myhost.com/mydb
```

I cannot directly change those config variables and I didn't find any way to specify their format in the heroku postgres dashboard.

Maybe there's a way to process it in python?

Comment: "I cannot directly change those config variables". This is ... odd. How does the Heroku app config variable get to Flask? Why can't you just parse and transform it on the way?

Comment: They are "protected" environment variables, that is, they are created by the postgres addons.

Comment: and you can't just read the env var and programatically pass the connection params to Flask, overriding whatever it'd otherwise read from the environment?